# Find the value of $x$, where $\sqrt{(2+\sqrt{3})^x} + \sqrt{(2-\sqrt{3})^x} = 2^x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$\sqrt{(2+\sqrt{3})^x} + \sqrt{(2-\sqrt{3})^x} = 2^x$$

I am not able to get to the result logically.

What I tried and got to this result
$$
LHS
= [(\sqrt{3}+1)/\sqrt{2}]^x +[(\sqrt{3}-1)/\sqrt{2}]^x
$$

Comment: what makes you believe it has a nice form?

Comment: The answer is $2$.

Comment: 2 is ONE solution. But that doesn't mean it is the only one.

Comment: Please prove your answer.

Comment: if you square both parts, you get $(2-\sqrt3)^x+(2+\sqrt3)^x=2^{2x}-2$. It seems $2$ is the only solution

Comment: This is not a precalculus-level problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{2+\sqrt3}4=\left(\dfrac{\sqrt3+1}{2\sqrt2}\right)^2$$

$\cos(45^\circ-30^\circ)=?$

$\sin(45-30)=?$

Finally $\sin^mA+\cos^mA$ is a decreasing function for $0\le A\le\dfrac\pi2$